# Android Application class not getting created in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have an hybrid application where i have overridden android Application class as below:

```
public class ContainerApplication extends DaggerApplication

//and then

public abstract class DaggerApplication extends Application
{
public static DaggerApplication instance;

public void onCreate() {       
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;       
    }
}

//then in my main activity 

public class MainActivity
extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        // this is a addModule method in my ContainerApplication class and the argument is some object which is not null;
        ContainerApplication.instance.addModule(object);     
    }
}


// I get an stack trace in google play store that the ContainerApplication.instance is null;

// the stacktrace for the same is as below:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.bell.selfserve.mybellmobile/com.pega.mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.pega.mobile.DaggerApplication.addModule(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.pega.mobile.DaggerApplication.addModule(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.pega.mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
```

I have properly provided the class details in the Android manifest file.Also this implementation works fine on most of the android devices and emulators with 7.0 but with some of the devices, specifically with Samsung devices the app crashes on `ContainerApplication.instance.addModule()` call, as can be seen in below stack trace line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.pega.mobile.DaggerApplication.addModule(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Also there is no multidex enabled in my app.

I have gone through lot of posts about issues of app crashed on android 7.0, but most of them have different reasons and not what I am getting in stack trace.

Also my manifest file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionCode="43" android:versionName="2.2.2" package="ca.bell.selfserve.mybellmobile.poc2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>\
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:description="@string/wifi_state_desc" android:label="@string/wifi_state_label" android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:description="@string/wifi_state_desc" android:label="@string/wifi_state_label" android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:description="@string/loc_permission_desc" android:label="@string/loc_permission_label" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
    <uses-permission android:description="@string/loc_permission_desc" android:label="@string/loc_permission_label" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/full_backup_content" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.pega.mobile.ContainerApplication" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.pega.mobile.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <provider android:authorities="ca.bell.selfserve.mybellmobile.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also  can this be an OS issue?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: show your manifest please

Comment: Please post all the Application classes under each other and properly formatted. Now I don't know where one ends and the other one starts and what fields are in each of them. ***///*** And as @anatoli suggested make sure you specified `<application android:name="your.package.ContainerApplication"` in the manifest.

Comment: because of the copyright issue I can not post all the classes , but I have posted the manifest of my application. Just updated the original post with manifest code

Comment: @susheeltickoo do you call `super.onCreate()` in `ContainerApplication` ? And why do you have abstract class for `Application`, while app can have only one `Application` class?

Comment: I have an ContainerApplication that extends DaggerApplication class and since i am doing instance =  this in onCreate() method of DaggerApplication class, i have to call super.onCreate() in ContainerApplication. Also these classes are part of a container that i am using from PEGA systems, this used to work fine on older version and rest of the android device